# error: unknown type name Game

Tags: c

Estoy modificando una aventura conversacional con TADS en c, he  creado un nuevo módulo `game_reader` al que le he añadido una función que antes estaba como privada en el módulo game.

La función utiliza la estructura de game que está en `game.h`.
Incluyo `game.h` en el `game_reader.h` y me sale un `error: unnknown type name Game`.
Es como si no se hubiera cargado ese archivo `game.h` en `game_reader.h`, como si no lo estuviera detectando.
Ya que en `game.h` hacía otra inclusión que es `types.h` y tampoco lo detecta en `game_reader.h` a no ser que la incluya directamente y no desde el `game.h`.

Esto es lo que hay en `game.h`:

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "game_reader.h"
#include "command.h"
#include "space.h"
#include "types.h"

typedef struct _Game
{
  Id player_location;
  Id object_location;
  Space *spaces[MAX_SPACES];
  T_Command last_cmd;
} Game;

STATUS game_create(Game *game);
STATUS game_create_from_file(Game *game, char *filename);
STATUS game_update(Game *game, T_Command cmd);
STATUS game_destroy(Game *game);
BOOL game_is_over(Game *game);
void game_print_data(Game *game);
Space *game_get_space(Game *game, Id id);
Id game_get_player_location(Game *game);
Id game_get_object_location(Game *game);
T_Command game_get_last_command(Game *game);
#endif
```

y esto es lo que hay en `game_reader.h`:

```
#ifndef GAME_READER_H
#define GAME_READER_H
#include "game.h"
#include "types.h"
STATUS game_load_spaces(Game *game, char *filename);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Para entender el problema que estás teniendo tienes que entender antes cómo funciona el proceso de compilación.

A la hora de compilar un programa en C se ejecutan 3 paso:

1. Se procesan las directivas del precompilador
2. Se genera el código objeto de cada unidad de compilación
3. Se enlazan los diferentes código objeto en el binario final

La fase del precompilador consiste, básicamente, en reemplazar todas las directivas del precompilador por código C válido. Así:

- Las macros se reemplazan por el valor al que representan
- Se evaluan los condicionales `#if` y se elimina el código que se encuentra con condiciones no válidas
- Las directivas `#include` se reemplazan por el contenido de los archivos a los que hacen referencia
- ...

La fase de compilación coge cada uno de los archivos de código `.c` y genera una suerte de código objeto. El código objeto es prácticamente código binario pero incompleto, pues el compilador aún no tiene toda la información (no sabe dónde se va a encontrar, físicamente, una función externa a dicho archivo).

La fase final consiste en coger todos los archivos generados en la fase anterior y unirlos en un único binario. En este punto se realizan las últimas operaciones de optimización y listo, ya tienes un ejecutable.

Pues bien, para entender el problema que nos ocupa debemos fijarnos en la fase del precompilador.

Tu tienes un archivo A que incluye al B a la vez que el B incluye al A. Lo que sucede es lo siguiente:

- Se procesa el `ifdef` del archivo **game.h**. Como la condición es cierta, aún no está definido el símbolo, se mantiene el código del archivo

  ```
  #define GAME_H

  #include "game_reader.h"
  #include "command.h"
  #include "space.h"
  #include "types.h"

  typedef struct _Game
  {
    Id player_location;
    Id object_location;
    Space *spaces[MAX_SPACES];
    T_Command last_cmd;
  } Game;

  // ...
  ```
- Se procesan los `#include`

  ```
  #define GAME_H

  #ifndef GAME_READER_H
  #define GAME_READER_H
  #include "game.h"
  #include "types.h"
  STATUS game_load_spaces(Game *game, char *filename);
  #endif

  // ...

  typedef struct _Game
  {
    Id player_location;
    Id object_location;
    Space *spaces[MAX_SPACES];
    T_Command last_cmd;
  } Game;

  // ...
  ```
- Se procesa la directiva `#ifndef GAME_READER_H`, la condición es cierta y el código que contiene se mantiene

  ```
  #define GAME_H

  #define GAME_READER_H
  #include "game.h"
  #include "types.h"
  STATUS game_load_spaces(Game *game, char *filename);

  // ...

  typedef struct _Game
  {
    Id player_location;
    Id object_location;
    Space *spaces[MAX_SPACES];
    T_Command last_cmd;
  } Game;

  // ...
  ```
- Se procesan los `#include` que han aparecido

  ```
  #define GAME_H

  #define GAME_READER_H

  #ifndef GAME_H
  #define GAME_H

  #include "game_reader.h"
  #include "command.h"
  #include "space.h"
  #include "types.h"

  typedef struct _Game
  {
    Id player_location;
    Id object_location;
    Space *spaces[MAX_SPACES];
    T_Command last_cmd;
  } Game;

  // ...

  #endif

  // ...

  STATUS game_load_spaces(Game *game, char *filename);

  // ...

  typedef struct _Game
  {
    Id player_location;
    Id object_location;
    Space *spaces[MAX_SPACES];
    T_Command last_cmd;
  } Game;

  // ...
  ```
- Se procesa la directiva `#ifndef GAME_H`. Ahora resulta que el símbolo sí que está definido, luego el código encerrado por la directiva se elimina:

  ```
  #define GAME_H

  #define GAME_READER_H

  // ...

  STATUS game_load_spaces(Game *game, char *filename);

  // ...

  typedef struct _Game
  {
    Id player_location;
    Id object_location;
    Space *spaces[MAX_SPACES];
    T_Command last_cmd;
  } Game;

  // ...
  ```

Como ves, el resultado es que tienes la función `game_load_spaces` declarada antes que esté declarado el tipo `Game`. Esto es lo que está provocando tu error. En C, dos cabeceras no se pueden incluir mutuamente.

Llegados a este punto tienes dos soluciones:

1. Mueves la declaración de `Game` a una cabecera en la que no haya funciones.
2. Recurres al uso de *declaration forward*

La segunda solución se aprovecha de cómo se compilan el código en C. En concreto, durante la fase de compilación el compilador asume que no tiene toda la información necesaria, y es por eso que genera código objeto en vez de binario ya ejecutable. Esa asunción nos permite decirle a C que un tipo determinado existe sin necesidad de declararlo en ese momento:

```
typedef struct _Game Game;
```

Poniendo esta declaración en `game_reader.h` romperás con esa dependencia mutua y el programa podrá compilar. Eso si, recuerda que ahora en `game_reader.c` sí que tendrás que añadir el include a `game_reader.h`. Si no lo haces, a la hora de acceder a las variables de `Game`, el compilador no sabrá cómo acceder a dichas variables.

**game_reader.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_READER_H
#define GAME_READER_H
typedef struct _Game Game; // Declaration_forward
#include "types.h"
STATUS game_load_spaces(Game *game, char *filename);
//                      ~~~~ Ahora el tipo ya existe
#endif
```

**game_reader.c**

```
#include "game.h"
// Ahora ya podremos acceder a las variables de Game, crear instancias, ...

// ...
```